# .net Regex for more than 5 consecutive alphabet letters

Tags: javascript, .net, regex

I am attempting to write a .Net Regex for more than 5 consecutive alphabet letters.

dfhjvudyfyreaaaaa - not allowed

dfhjvudyfyreAAAAA - not allowed

dfhjvAAAAAfyreAAA - not allowed

dfhjvAAAfyresdAAA - allowed

dfhjvAAAf3434yresdA - allowed

So far, i have tried some reg exp but, not working as per my requirement.

**My requirement are below**

1. String length should be less than 25 character
2. String is Combination of alphabet/number only, not allow special character.

**Solution tried**

1. ^(?=.{1,25}$)(([a-zA-Z0-9])\5?(?!\5))+$
2. (?i)(.)\1\1

I will used string to represent vehicle engine number or chassis number.

I am okey, if there possible solution in JavaScript.

Can we build this type of regex in .net?

Comment: Create multiple regexes: they would be much easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
^(?![a-zA-Z0-9]*([a-zA-Z0-9])\1{4})[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,24}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vI8EuD/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?![a-zA-Z0-9]*([a-zA-Z0-9])\1{4})` - no 5 consecutive alphanumeric chars anywhere inside the string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,24}`  - 1 to 24 alphanumeric chars
- `$` -  end of string.

If you set a case insensitive flag, you will make the backreference also case insensitive (`aaAAA` will also fail the match). In .NET, you may pass the flag as `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` option, and in JS, add `i` modifier.

C# implementation:

```
bool valid = Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^(?![a-z0-9]*([a-z0-9])\1{4})[a-z0-9]{1,24}\z", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I suggest `\z` in .NET because it always matches at the very end of the string while `$` can match before a final newline char (not the case in JS).

In JS, you may use

```
var valid = /^(?![a-z0-9]*([a-z0-9])\1{4})[a-z0-9]{1,24}$/i.test(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

With the case insensitive flag, you can write it using a negative lookahead to test if there isn't five consecutive characters:

```
^(?!.*(.)\1{4})[A-Z0-9]{1,25}$
```